# Thread-safe timing to align data collected in multiple threads- does QElapsedTimer work?

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety, timing

I'm working on an application (`c++`) that utilizes multiple types of hardware to simultaneously collect data of various types. The common usage pattern is to run the different interfaces to these devices (eye-tracking, motion-tracking, visualization, etc.) each in its own thread, so they mess with each other as little as possible. I don't a need a guarantee of super-precise timing of when the threads actually execute, which I understand would require hardware timers. What I'm looking to do, though, is have threads be able to query a central timer of some kind, which they can use periodically to add time-stamps to the collected data, so the data can be (semi-precisely) aligned later for analysis. Millisecond-scale precision is fine for this purpose.

The application uses `Qt` for gui purposes, so I thought [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qelapsedtimer.html) would be a potential solution. However, the docs state that all methods are [reentrant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html), not thread-safe. Am I correct that this necessitates a unique `QElapsedTimer` object for each thread that wishes to use this type of timing functionality? If this is the case, my approach would be to require each thread to initialize timing in a blocking function (executed in the main thread). Initialization would involve creating a wrapper object which combines a timer + an offset from the "main" timer, so that any/all timers created are "synchronized" to the main timer. This would be done in the main thread in order to obtain the offset from the non-threadsafe original timer.

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better "standard" (design-pattern) approach that I should use instead? Or, is there a different library that would better suit my purposes? Currently I'm working on Windows (7 and XP), but the application eventually is slated to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt you have convenient classes such as QMutexLocker for making synchronous calls. So you can use QMutexLocker along with QMutex in order to mark the function as thread safe, and then you can use QElapsedTimer across threads without any problems.

Comment: Thanks... was looking for a way to avoid having to lock a mutex each time the function is called, but it may be the best approach. I'm implementing it this way for now, I may need to change to something akin to my original suggestion if it proves to be more expensive to do it this mutexed way.

Answer (score 1):

Reentrant means you need to have at least one different instance for each thread if you want to access simultaneously. You can also use QDateTime for generating timestamps, but that is not thread safe as well. I think therefore it would be better to mutex the access to that method.